# How to open a context menu by long pressing on a disabled button?

Tags: android, listview, button, contextmenu

I have a listview for which I registered a context menu.
On the list view row I have buttons.
What I need is to be able to long press on a DISABLED button in order to access the row context menu.

I tried to add a long click listener on the button itself but it doesn't work when the button is disabled:

```
                button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        activity.openContextMenu(v);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Any idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

A disabled button cannot listen to any event, but you can customize your own button by extending Button class to make your own definition of disabling